# How to replace '{Name}' in java

Tags: java, special-characters

I need to replace a value in a string like `{Name}` with values. 
How can we replace the special character `{` and `}`? 
I have tried this:

```
str.replaceAll("{Name}","A");
```

But this doesnt work if we have special characters.

Comment: try to scape characters with str.replaceAll("\\{Name\\}","A");

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), the `.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` method takes in a regular expression as the first parameter.

It so happens that `{` and `}` have special meaning in regular expression syntax and thus need to be *escaped*. Try using `str.replaceAll("\\{Name\\}","A");`.

The extra `\` in front instructs the regular expression engine to threat the `{` and `}` as actual characters (without their special meaning). Since this is Java, you need to also escape the `\` character which is why you need two of them.

Comment: `replaceAll` for a literal replacement is overkill.

Comment: Overkill but popular, copied from one code to the next without any reflection

Comment: @npinti: What loop? `replace` replaces all occurrences, just like `replaceAll` does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah sorry my bad, confused it with something else.

Comment: Thank u.. using the escape char worked.,
str.replaceAll("\\{Name\\}","A");

Comment: @Akhila: You're welcome. Although if you are not using regular expressions, what `T.J. Crowder` recommends is better.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) rather than `replaceAll`, since `replace` doesn't expect and parse a regular expression.

Example: ([live copy](http://ideone.com/vBTCcs))

```
String str = "Here it is: {Name} And again: {Name}";
System.out.println("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace("{Name}","A");
System.out.println("After: " + str);
```

Output:

```
Before: Here it is: {Name} And again: {Name}
After: Here it is: A And again: A
```